esp-tls-mbedtls: No server verification option set in esp_tls_cfg_t structure. Check esp_tls API reference
I am working on ESP32S3 microcontroller with ESP32-IDF V5.1.2 where I am getting following error log
E (55888) esp-tls-mbedtls: No server verification option set in esp_tls_cfg_t structure. Check esp_tls API reference
E (55889) esp-tls-mbedtls: Failed to set client configurations, returned [0x8017] (ESP_ERR_MBEDTLS_SSL_SETUP_FAILED)
E (55900) esp-tls: create_ssl_handle failed
E (55905) esp-tls: Failed to open new connection
E (55910) transport_base: Failed to open a new connection
E (55919) HTTP_CLIENT: Connection failed, sock < 0
E (55922) HTTP_CLIENT: Failed to open HTTP connection: ESP_ERR_HTTP_CONNECT

The same code works fine when accessing http URL but when used https URL this is the error code I get
First
I thought it is because I didn't provide CA certificate so I added it in code. Then I get this following error log
E (128542) esp-tls-mbedtls: mbedtls_ssl_handshake returned -0x6C00
I (128543) esp-tls-mbedtls: Certificate verified.
E (128544) esp-tls: Failed to open new connection
E (128549) transport_base: Failed to open a new connection
E (128559) HTTP_CLIENT: Connection failed, sock < 0
E (128561) HTTP_CLIENT: Failed to open HTTP connection: ESP_ERR_HTTP_CONNECT

When I tracked -0x6C00 code in IDF it says
/** Internal error (eg, unexpected failure in lower-level module) */
#define MBEDTLS_ERR_SSL_INTERNAL_ERROR                    -0x6C00

Is it because the method I used to create CA certificate is wrong , then what is the correct one and/or there are other parameters that I have to set in code to make it work for https. with CA certificate.
Thank You

Hi, welcome to SO. Unfortunately we can't help you without seeing your code. I'd recommend you take the Tour and read How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example.

This issue is resolved as the wrong callback function was assigned to fsend function of MbedTLS context structure.
Thank You.
